# dart - does `this` depend on the point of invocation

Tags: dart

```
class mButton extends StatefulWidget{
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final Widget child;

  const mButton({Key key, this.onPressed, this.child}):super(key: key);

  @override
  _mButtonState createState()=>_mState();
}

class _mButtonState extends State<mButton>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: _getColors(),      #notice this line
        child: widget.child,
        onPressed: widget.onPressed,
      )
    );
  }

  Color _getColors(){
    return _buttonColors.putIfAbsent(this, ()=> colors[next(0,5)]);   #notice `this` in here
  }

  Map<_mButtonState, Color> _buttonColors = {};
  final _random = Random();
  int next(int min, int max) => min+_random.nextInt(max-min);
  List<Color> colors = [
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.orange,
    Colors.purple,
    Colors.amber,
    Colors.lightBlue
  ];

}
```

In the above code, notice the two lines marked with `#notice`. The `this` keyword is supposed to refer to the current class instance, but *from the above code*, it almost makes the impression that the `_getColors()` method is trying to make `this` refer to every new instance of `RaisedButton` instantiated.

I'm a bit confused, does `this` refer to the instance of `_mButtonState`   **or**
every new instance of `RaisedButton` instantiated(this would be done by instantiating mButton stateful widget) ?

Comment: It refers to `_mButtonState` instance

Comment: It's pretty clear from `_buttonColors`'s declaration that it stores an `_mButtonState` as its key.  However, as presented, the `_buttonColors` `Map` makes no sense since it will only ever one member, which is a reference to the object it's a member of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it almost makes the impression that the _getColors() method is trying to make this refer to every new instance of `RaisedButton` instantiated

This wouldn't actually be possible here, because the instance of `RaisedButton` cannot be created until after `_getColors()` has been called (since the return value of `_getColors()` is passed into `RaiseButton`'s constructor).

`this` will be `_mButtonState`. Although `this` can be a bit confusing in JavaScript, in Dart you can always tell what `this` will be from looking at the definition of the method, without concern for how/where it's called.